# Stretching Animation

Tags: animation

Relatively new to Blender here. Some questions I have, any help is very much appreciated!

I’m thinking of doing an animation of respiration where the ribs move up and down. However to animate the muscles in between the ribs, I can’t just move the muscles by scaling / rotating / movement since the ribs also have some rotation.

Thus I was wondering if there is any way, at all, to join the upper and lower surface of the muscles to the ribs such that as the ribs move, the muscles move accordingly as well.

I don’t know how to express this well in google searches and so I’ve not been able to come up with a solution. All I've been able to find is the Stretch to constraint but it's not working well for me.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

[image: Before inhalation, ribs are down][image: After inhalation, when ribs are up. The muscles between the ribs have not moved (I need help with moving them accurately)]

Answer (score 0):

Give each Muscle two *Hook Modifier*s, one for the top, one for the bottom:
[image]

For each muscle, create two according Vertex Groups in Weight Paint Mode (Hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> key for dragging a smooth gradient) and feed them into the Modifiers.

[image]

When you set a rib bone as target *Object* in each Modifier, the muscle should stretch and follow the two bones' movements:

[image]